# echo prints after the semicolon

Tags: php, html, web

I am using NVU for web development and I encountered a problem that I have searched to fix for quite some time.

```
<?php 
$imagesDir = 'images/'; 
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($images as $key=>$value)
{
      echo "<img src='"$value"'>" ;
}
?>
```

I should get an output of all the images in the "images/" folder, but my output looks like this

> " ; } ?>

it only prints what comes after it and none of what I actually want it to print. 
What should I do? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure a PHP interpreter is being run on your file?

Comment: How would I check if it is?

Comment: Look at the source code of your file that is being outputted - suspect that there is more than what is showing up on the browser.

Comment: I do not have any sort of output from this as it is not a live site. Im building it on my laptop and then sending it to the server

Comment: PHP is probably not being parsed. What is your extension name on your files?

Comment: it is .html how would I parse it, I cant seem to find any way to add one to the file. The code works when I change it which means the PHP code words just fine but any time I echo something it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're missing the periods..

```
  echo "<img src='".$value."'>" ;
```

You can also put in variables within double quotation marks in PHP without the need to concatenate the string.

```
echo "<img src='$value'>";
```

Comment: Thanks for all the speedy replies, but none of these do anything different to the output.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the concatenation operator

```
echo "<img src='" . $value . "'>" ;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it prints the same thing as before.

Answer (score 1):

you're mising the periods:

```
echo "<img src='".$value."'>" ;
```

Also it is worth always checking the error log, take a look at the PHP error log (or if not filtered, the server error log).